# Generate a list of filenames in a directory, modify the filename but still be able to access the full path winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, file, file-io

I am creating an application using C# and WinForms. I have a code that recursively loops through the directory to get the file name. I then modify the file name and display the modified name in a `ListBox`. My issue is that I lost the full path. I need to retain the full path for further processing but not displayed on the `ListBox`.

```
foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(path))
{
    String displayedName = "";
    String fullPath = fileName;
    if (fileName.Contains("tsv"))
    {
        try
        {
            //make changes here
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}

foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
{
    FindFiles(directory);
}
```

Comment: create a custom type which holds the path and override the .ToString method to only display filename. Then you can get the path from the selecteditem as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what I'm talking about. You should be able to incorporate this into your existing code as it's nothing more than creating a class, putting the info into the object and then shows how to get it back. Just add a button and a listbox to a new project and put this code in the appropriate places.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string DemoPath = @"D:\MyImages\MyPicture.jpg";

        string filestring = Path.GetFileName(DemoPath); //filename only
        string pathstring = Path.GetDirectoryName(DemoPath); //path only
        MyFileInfo nfo = new MyFileInfo(); //instantiate your object
        nfo.fileName = filestring; //fill the properties
        nfo.filePath = pathstring;
        listBox1.Items.Add(nfo); //add it to the listbox (only filename shows)
     }

    private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //cast the selected item back to the MyFileInfoType and get its filePath
        string pathFromSelection = (listBox1.SelectedItem as MyFileInfo).filePath;
        MessageBox.Show(pathFromSelection);
    }


class MyFileInfo
{
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string filePath { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //Here we tell the object to only display the filename
        return fileName;
    }
}
```